# How to make my static website a Wordpress template?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I've just finished making a website which is not a blog using HTML and CSS, I want to use Wordpress as CMS so the person for whom I made the website can easily modify a certain section of this website like header image, certain div contents etc. How to achieve this because a lot of resources I find on the internet is about making a Wordpress blog template. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Download a theme layout here https://underscores.me/, and replace with your codes. PHP Knowledge is must.

Comment: I do like the idea of this, but I think it would benefit him more to spend the time learning to build themes from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to know PHP and convert a lot of elements of the HTML template into a PHP WordPress template, it's more complicated than just uploading the template and changing a few things, I've gathered a few links on how you can do it yourself, but if you don't have the time/knowledge to do it yourself I've listed a few sites where you can find people to do it for you (it'll cost you),

**TIP:** I'd stick to the tutorials if I were you, paying someone to do it for you can get a little pricey and you'll learn more doing it yourself in the long run.

[Converting HTML to Wordpress (TUTORIAL)](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/converting-html-sites-to-wordpress-sites)

[HTML TO WORDPRESS (TUTORIAL)](https://websitesetup.org/html-to-wordpress/)

[Freelancer (Pay for someone to do it)](https://freelancer.com)

[Upwork (Pay for someone to do it)](https://upwork.com)